# Bootstrap adjust dropdown-menu width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am using a dropdown-menu to show the candidate options I can choose. And I also want an input to filter the options, so when I enter something, the dropdown-menu should also be shown. So I want to adjust the width of the dropdown-menu to be equal to the input. And how can I show it when the I enter something in the input?

The html I current use is:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /btn-group -->
```

[image]

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Have you tried adding your own CSS rule to make the dropdown field 100% width of the parent div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are searching for some kind of suggestion search box with given selectable choices if I understood correctly.

See this thread:[twitter bootstrap autocomplete dropdown / combobox with Knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902010/twitter-bootstrap-autocomplete-dropdown-combobox-with-knockoutjs)

Solution suggestions: [selectize.js](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) or [Select2](https://select2.github.io/)

The aspect of automatically adjusting the dropdown's width to be equal to the input's width is hard to achieve because it would cut off some of your given choices (example: Input is only one character - Dropdown would only show first character of every choice). This can't be what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I actually want to let the dropdown-menu's width be equal to the <input> element's, not the user's input. And it seems that selectize.js is what I want. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

possible solution:

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').width($('.input-group').width());
```

```css
.input-group{
  width:33%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
<div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /btn-group -->
```

Comment: Thanks but can't I automatically adjust the width to be equal to the input's width? Your solution is apparently fixed width and that's not what I want.

Comment: Only javascript solution as far as i can see

Comment: I have updated my solution with a jquery solution.  Now the width changes according to the input width